# Trap signal using kill in child process?

Tags: c, signals, shared-memory

Working on Linux, I want to catch the signal I have sent using `kill` in the child process and then print the loop but I don't know how.

I can't seem to get my code that catches the signal.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h> 

int SHMSIZE = 9;
int alarmFlag = 0;

void main()
{
 int shmid; 
 int *shm; 
 pid_t pid = fork();

 if(pid == 0) {
  pause();
  shmid = shmget(4000, SHMSIZE, 0);
  shm = shmat(shmid,0,0);

  int i;
  for(i=0;i<SHMSIZE;i++)
   printf("<%d , ",shm[i]);
 }
 else
 {
   int *n;
   shmid = shmget(4000,SHMSIZE,0666 | IPC_CREAT);
   shm = shmat(shmid,0,0);
   n = shm;  

   int i;
   for(i=0;i<SHMSIZE;i++)
    n[i] = i;

   int result = kill(pid, SIGUSR1); 
   wait(NULL);  
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to catch signals, you must use [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) (or possibly [`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html)) to set the catching function, etc.  You've not set any signal handling.  You also need to think about sizes of shared memory; the size is specified in bytes, but you're trying to use units of `sizeof(int)`, so you're accessing memory out of bounds.

Comment: If you're working on Linux, the return type of `main()` must be `int`.  If you're not getting warnings from GCC, you need to add to your compilation flags (`gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror` works well for me).

Comment: Your edit is *not* an improvement!  There are 2,400 questions related to signals on SO; the answer to (what's left of) your question is almost certainly in one of those — probably many of them.  Did you look for code that illustrates more or less what you need?  Incidentally, when you had code on display, it was the parent that was sending the signal, not the child as you ask about in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `pause()` in your program on its own doesn't catch a signal, it just sleeps until a signal is delivered, but if that signal isn't caught (using [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) or [`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html), as Jonathan Leffler wrote), it terminates the process. So, you have to add e. g. `signal(SIGUSR1, catch);` before `pause();` and

```
void catch(int signum) { }
```

before `main()`.